# button click causing another button to trigger

Tags: java, jbutton

I am working on a project that requires a user to login. The GUI I have has `login`, `quit` and an ATM numpad below that. The `numpad` has `0-9`, `clear` and `ok`. I would like to use the `ok` button to trigger login once `ok` button is clicked. Is there a way for me to do so?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (e.getSource() == keypad[i])
    {
        //Edit the input display
        passINPUT = passINPUT + i;
        pass.setText(passINPUT);
    }
}

if(e.getSource() == clear){
    passINPUT = "";
    pass.setText(passINPUT);       
}

if(e.getSource() == OK){}
```

Comment: Yes there is a way. But more details where you are stuck would be helpfull. Currently it appears to me that you would like us to write the function for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The solution is to use

```
buttonName.doClick();
```